# JSONException No Value

Tags: java, android, json

I'm have created the following json array of price and mobile model name. This data is read from a wamp phpmyadmin server with table name as "products":

```
    {
    "products": [
        {
            "pid": "14",
            "name": "zxc",
            "price": "123456"
        },
        {
            "pid": "6",
            "name": "Sony    Xperia",
            "price": "35000"
        },
        {
            "pid": "8",
            "name": "Samsung Galaxy Note",
            "price": "32000"
        },
        {
            "pid": "5",
            "name": "htc",
            "price": "26326"
        },
        {
            "pid": "9",
            "name": "Nokia Lumia 800",
            "price": "18000"
        },
        {
            "pid": "2",
            "name": "iphone",
            "price": "12345"
        },
        {
            "pid": "15",
            "name": "sdjnas",
            "price": "12243"
        },
        {
            "pid": "13",
            "name": "Samsung S5222",
            "price": "6500"
        },
        {
            "pid": "11",
            "name": "Nokia C201",
            "price": "4400"
        },
        {
            "pid": "7",
            "name": "Nokia Asha 200",
            "price": "4000"
        },
        {
            "pid": "1",
            "name": "htc",
            "price": "1234"
        },
        {
            "pid": "3",
            "name": "htc",
            "price": "1234"
        },
        {
            "pid": "4",
            "name": "htc",
            "price": "1234"
        },
        {
            "pid": "10",
            "name": "aks",
            "price": "1234"
        },
        {
            "pid": "12",
            "name": "asd",
            "price": "123"
        }
    ],
    "success": 1
}
```

I have problem with the following block of code:

```
    try 
    {
        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

        if (success == 1)
        {
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                }
        }

            else
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewProductActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
    }

    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Where tags are simple string values:

```
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
```

Whenever i run this code it show in the logcat it shows JSONException No Value for success. I'm not able to figure out what is exactly causing this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you print the **json** ?

Comment: what is json. is it a jsonobject?

Comment: @Hariharan yaa the string which i just gave above was printed in the logact

Comment: @GiruBhai "success" is there in the last with value equal to 1

Comment: @Raghunandan yes json is a json object

Comment: Please post Webservices url

Comment: Are you receiving json output in response ? Please check it first. You parsing code looks fine to me

Comment: @EngrWaseemArain url is a localhost address. But i don't think there would be any issue with the url. I already have the complete json object.

Comment: @HardikTrivedi i'm kind of not getting what you want to say. Every time this code is run i have a json exception for no value of "success".

Comment: If your url is of localhost and running code in emulator u need to provide different ip like http:// 10.0.2.2:8080 / provide IP and port number both. Becuase android dont't understand what localhost is. And first print reponse whatever you are getting after sending request to server. I doubt that your code is not receiving proper json response. JSONException is triggered when String is not a valid json

Comment: @HardikTrivedi I had already provided the actual ip in thr url

Comment: Try printing `json.toString()` right before doing `int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);` and see if it matches the json you posted here

Comment: Please tell whether you are running it on emulator ? Also tell the ip ?

Answer (score 1):

Check that:

```
JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(URL,
                    POST, params);
```

From there [How to httpPost() to covert httpGet()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098040/how-to-httppost-to-covert-httpget/22980301#22980301)

Comment: I have a JSONParser class which already implements the things this way only.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this,

The method you are using to get the `JSON` say `getJSONFromUrl()`

Change the `HttpPost` to `HttpGet`

Please refer to this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220366/jsonexception-no-value-for-data)